# How can I add a word blacklist to this php API?

Tags: php

so recently I have followed a tutorial online which taught me about making an API. The API works perfectly fine, but I want to add a blacklist of words and url's in it. How do I do it? Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');

include_once '../config/Database.php';
include_once '../models/Student.php';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

  $db = new Database();
  $db = $db->connect();

  $student = new Student($db);

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $student->title = $data->title;
  $student->fromuser = $data->fromuser;
  $student->useremail = $data->useremail;
  $student->location = $data->location;
  $student->description = $data->description;

  if($student->postData()) {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'GeekyGO > Item was added successfully!'));
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => 'GeekyGO > Error while adding the item!'));
  }
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('message' => "Error: incorrect Method!"));
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some blacklist examples?

Comment: @JunPan Well it's swearword and offensive words I want to blacklist. I forgot a piece of my code and put it on Pastebin: [link](https://pastebin.com/HDQNiNNC)

Comment: Do the words you want to block are in the `$data` variable? If the word is on the blacklist, then what do you want to do?

Comment: @JunPan yes they are in the data variable and I would like to just send an error message.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the blacklist?